# Vim on Ubuntu 14.04 uses a funny python path, python can't import _io among other modules

Tags: python, linux, vim

All of a sudden (probably after a package update or something) vim stopped working with YouCompleteMe and throws:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/io.py", line 51, in <module>
    import _io
ImportError: No module named _io
```

(this also happens when I try to import io from inside vim using `:python import io`).

I've been battling this for the last couple of hours, no idea what the problem is, reinstalled python and vim several times, both from source and from aptitude, no difference. I've noticed that python inside vim uses a funny path compared to from the command line:

```
~$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys; print sys.path
['', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode']
>>>
```

And from vim:

```
:python import sys; print sys.path
['/usr/lib/python27.zip', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-pa
ckages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode', '_vim_path_']
```

I am not using`virtualenv` (I've noticed some people running into this with `virtualenv` set up).

Also must point out that Python works perfectly fine from the command line and I can happily import `io` when launching the interpreter and that this happens with both vim 8 compiled from source and vim-nox from aptitude.

Is it an issue with how python sees its `path` inside vim? I'm at my wits' end, no idea what to do to fix this.

Comment: I'm not so sure this problem is related to `sys.path`, but it is easily tested by setting `sys.path` in Vim to the value you get in Python: `:py sys.path = ['', '/usr/lib/python2.7', ...]`.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't think of trying that, will do when I get home as this is on my home machine. However, would be great if there's a way to control how python or vim initialise `sys.path` if indeed the fix lies in that.

Comment: It's possible that your YouCompleteMe plugin was built against an older version of Python and now needs to be reinstalled. Try going to the YouCompleteMe directory (mine is `~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe`) and running `install.sh`. That will rebuild YouCompleteMe.

Comment: @JimStewart Hi and thank you for comment, unfortunately even if I disable and completely remove YouCompleteMe the issue persists with vim (unable to run `:python import io`), I'm tempted to do a complete reinstall of my system as I've no idea what it could be the cause.

Answer (score 1):

YouCompleteMe provides an option [g:ycm_server_python_interpreter](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe#the-gycm_server_python_interpreter-option) to set a specific interpreter.

Just add `let g:ycm_server_python_interpreter = path/to/your/interpreter` in your `.vimrc` with the path of your favored interpreter.